# Meaning of the sentence from the song "Powerless"

Tags: meaning, sentence, lyrics

As I am not a native English speaker, I am a bit curious to know the meaning of this sentence which I heard in Nelly Furtado's song "Powerless":

> 'Cause this life is too short to live it just for you.

What does it mean?

1. Life is too short to spend it with you, meaning that I don't want to waste time on you.
2. Life seems too short and I want some more to spend it with you.

I know it is a bit of an awkward question but I thought this was the best place to ask it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it means "Life is too short to live it the way you want me to."

The song "Powerless" is all about living your life the way you want it to, and not letting others dictate you.